# Call a member method over a collection

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to know if something like that it's possible in C++11. The idea here is to have a class keeping reference to a collection and provide a generic method to perform some operations over it. With the following code I have problems to call a method of the class of each item in the collection using bind:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class Foo {
public:
    void print() {
        cout << "hello" << endl;
    }
};

class Helper {
private:
    vector<Foo> v;
public:
    Helper() :
            v(5) {
    }
    void perform(std::function<void(Foo&)>&& f) {
        for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), f);
    }
};

int main() {
    Helper r;
    r.perform(bind(&Foo::print)); //it doesn't work
    r.perform([](Foo& f) {f.print();}); //it works
}
```

I guess `bind` wants a real instance of Foo. I'm wondering if it's possible to use bind instead of lambda. I'm asking just because I want to understand how C++11 works. Is it needed `bind` with `mem_fn`?

Comment: I just want to point out that it is recommended to use `lambda`s over `std::bind` and `std::mem_fn`.

Comment: @super Thanks for your comment. I'm just here to learn, so if you want to point out why it could be great

Comment: They are easier to read and understand, and they have a better chance of being inlined by the compiler during optimization. In C++11 there can be a few exceptions where you need bind, but from C++14 and onward there is nothing bind can do that a lambda can not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible to use `std::bind` in your case. Like you said, `std::bind` expects an instance of `Foo`. As its name suggests, it is used to *bind* objects to functions that won't change, so that you don't have to pass that object every time.

```
void foo(int, bool) {}

int A = 10;
foo(A, false);
foo(A, true);

// now instead, I can "bind" A to foo.
auto foo2 = std::bind(&foo, A, std::placeholders::_1);
foo2(false);
foo2(true);
```

But don't worry, you can pass `&Foo::print` directly. Why? Because `perform` takes a function with a first parameter of `Foo&`, which is exactly what `print` takes (it doesn't have any explicit parameters, but has an implicit `Foo&` one).

```
r.perform(&Foo::print);
```

Comment: Thanks. This solve the question. Just another question, if print had a parameter?

Comment: @greywolf82 Then you will need to provide the parameters yourself. Either you can pass them to `perform`, or use `std::bind` or a lambda :)

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways of doing that. But first, you need to understand what your problem is:

```
void perform(std::function<void(Foo&)>&& f) {
```

The parameter is a callable object that takes a `Foo &` as its parameter, and returns a `void`. That's what this declares.

```
r.perform(bind(&Foo::print));
```

The purpose of `std::bind` is to wrap one callable object and supply default values for some of those parameters, while forwarding the remaining parameters from the calling context.

There are no default parameters here to bind to anything. In the context of callable objects, a class method, such as `Foo::print` takes a pointer to its object as its first parameter, which, in this case, would be `Foo *`, the actual object to invoke, and here there is no default object to bind to anything. There's nothing here for `std::bind` do to. It cannot possibly service any logical purpose here.

The second issue is:

```
for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), f);
```

`for_each` passes ***a reference*** to the object in the collection, to the callable object specified for its third argument. Here, somehow you want to end up with a class method here, but the class method takes a ***pointer*** to the object.

Setting aside the issue of how to make everything fit together, there's no direct way to reconcile the two. One "thing" wants a pointer, the other thing wants a reference. You have to change something.

Changing this `for_each` is fairly trivial:

```
void perform(const std::function<void(Foo *)> &f) {
    for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [&](auto &g){ f(&g); });
}
```

Now, `perform` takes a callable object that takes a pointer as its first argument, and uses an internal lambda to do the requisite conversion.

And how to call this? You don't need `std::bind`:

```
r.perform(&Foo::print);
```

That's it. `std::function`'s constructor will take care of wrapping everything up.

Comment: I tried my code removing just bind and it works now, so I ddidn't understand the problem between reference and pointer in your reply.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is receive a pointer to a `Foo` method and call it iterating over the `Foo` element in the `v` vector.

I mean... something like

```
  void performMethod (void(Foo::*f)())
   {
     for ( auto & obj : v )
        (obj.*f)();
   }
```

that can be called as

```
r.performMethod(&Foo::print);
```